# What is the format of a patch file?

Tags: patch, file-format

What does the following mean ?

```
diff -rBNu src.orig/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java src/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java
--- src.orig/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java 2009-03-10 11:34:01.000000000 -0700
+++ src/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java  2009-03-10 14:11:55.000000000 -0700
@@ -4,9 +4,12 @@

+  int CJK = 21;
+  int DIGIT = 22;

   int DEFAULT = 0;

   String[] tokenImage = {
     "<EOF>",
+    "\"OR\"",
     "<WORD>",
     "<ACRONYM>",
     "<SIGRAM>",
@@ -39,6 +42,8 @@
     "\"\\\"\"",
     "\":\"",
     "\"/\"",
+    "\"(\"",
+    "\")\"",
     "\".\"",
     "\"@\"",
     "\"\\\'\"",
```

Comment: for git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff/31615438#31615438

Comment: See the GNU [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified)...and the [full thing](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents)

Answer (score 158):

The `-u` option you used specifies the unified format. In that format the first two lines is a header: `---` is the original file, `+++` is the new file, and the timestamps.

#### `@@` block headers

That is then followed by chunks (change hunks) that starts with the `@@ -R,r +R,r @@` syntax.

Those are two ranges, the one with the `-` is the range for the chunk in the original file, and the one with the `+` the range in the new file.  The `R` designates the line number where the diff operation is started.

The numbers after the comma are *the number of affected lines in each file*.

- Every time you **remove** a line, the `+r` number will be **smaller** than `-r`.
- Every time you **add** a line, the `+r` number will be **bigger** than `-r`
- Changing a line will add `0` to the `+r` number.  (same scope of lines)

#### Chunks of code lines

Within these chunks lines are identified as additions or deletions `-` means delete, `+` means addition. Lines that did not change in that chunk will have neither `+` or `-` front of it.

In your example it means there are two chunks, or sections, that changed between the two files and the lines with `+` in it are the new ones added, nothing was deleted.

You can find much more information about the syntax by doing a google search for unified diff.

Comment: You mentioned "@@ -R +R @@" syntax,but it's in fact "@@ -R,r +R,r @@",what does the other number mean?

Comment: the numbers after the comma are the number of affected lines in each file.  Every time you remove a line, the `+r` number will be smaller than `-r`. Every time you add a line, the `+r` number will be bigger than `-r`

Comment: @NewAlexandria I'd reformat this so that when listing items, each item is on separate line, indented.

Comment: @AndreMiller how do we identify no of lines added, deleted, modified seperately in `git diff`'

Comment: `Lines that did not change in that chunk will have neither + or - front of it.` I think it would be more accurate/specific to say it will have a space in front of it. This is important, because if a line in a changed file started with `@@`, it must not be confused with the diff syntax.

Comment: Alternative explanation of the `r`: `-r` is the number of lines in the chunk of the original file; `+r` is the number of lines in the chunk in the new file. Basically, count the number of lines *in the chunk* before and after the change.

Answer (score 35):

The old file name

```
--- src.orig/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java 2009-03-10 11:34:01.000000000 -0700
```

The new file name

```
+++ src/java/org/apache/nutch/analysis/NutchAnalysisConstants.java  2009-03-10 14:11:55.000000000 -0700
```

- `-4`: chunk begins at line 4 in old file (including context lines);
- `9`: number of lines in the chunk in old file including context lines (so total of lines that have a `-` or nothing in front of them);
- `+4`: chunk begins at line 4 in the new file;
- `12`: number of lines in the chunk in new file including context lines (so total of lines that have a `+` or nothing in front of them).

*Notice*: I changed the diff to include a modified line, so a deleted line followed by an added line.

```
@@ -4,9 +4,12 @@

+  int CJK = 21;
+  int DIGIT = 22;

-  int DEFAULT = 0;
+  int DEFAULT = 42;

   String[] tokenImage = {
     "<EOF>",
+    "\"OR\"",
     "<WORD>",
     "<ACRONYM>",
     "<SIGRAM>",
```

Same as above, but notice the chunk in the new file starts 3 lines further because the previous chunk added a net worth of 3 lines.

```
@@ -39,6 +42,8 @@
     "\"\\\"\"",
     "\":\"",
     "\"/\"",
+    "\"(\"",
+    "\")\"",
     "\".\"",
     "\"@\"",
     "\"\\\'\"",
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the 9 and 12 in this example

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you're asking.
Diff shows you the differences between two files. In your case you're diffing `NutchAnalysisConstants.java` from two different places and generating information about those differences.

`-r` to diff means "recursive diff," although in this case it does nothing since you're diffing files, not directories.

`-B` means to ignore changes that only involve blank lines.

`-N` means that if in directory1 I have a file, but it isn't present in directory2, diff should treat it as if the file is present but empty in directory2 (thus effectively giving you the full contents of the file in directory1).

`-u` means to use the unified output format, which is only supported by GNU diff and GNU patch.

As for what the output means, this [link](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/introduction-using-diff-and-patch) may be useful for you.

Comment: Link not found. Please fix your comment

Answer (score 1):

The `+` characters mean that those lines were added since the last version of `NutchAnalysisConstants.java`. The `@@` line is telling you that the diff has jumped to another section of the file, in this case line 39 in the original, or line 43 in the new.

Comment: @@ -39,6 +43,8 @@

what does 6 and 8 mean specifically?

Comment: It's the number of lines the change hunk applies to for the respective file. So, for the old file, it applies to 6 lines, vs 8 for the new file.

Comment: But it turns out that new file is not changed ,is that by design?