# How to understand diff -u in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

example code

```
diff -r -u -P a.c b.c > diff.patch
```

I've tried to search in man.

man says that diff -u is to unify the pattern of output, what is the meaning of that and when should we use it?

thanks a lot.

Comment: See the output with & without -u option. You will understand.. & for creating a patch, you'll most likely need to use -u.

Comment: Use `diff -u` if you want an incomprehensible mess :) But really it just puts the differences inline with the file and uses + and - before the lines to symbolise before and after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read the output from git diff\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff)

Answer (score 14):

From [Wikipedia (diff utility)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format):

> The *unified format* (or *unidiff*) inherits the technical improvements made by the context format, but produces a smaller diff with old and new text presented immediately adjacent. Unified format is usually invoked using the "-u" command line option. This output is often used as input to the patch program. Many projects specifically request that "diffs" be submitted in the unified format, making unified diff format the most common format for exchange between software developers.
>
> ...
>
> The format starts with the same two-line header as the context format, except that the original file is preceded by `"---"` and the new file is preceded by `"+++"`. Following this are one or more change hunks that contain the line differences in the file. The unchanged, contextual lines are preceded by a space character, addition lines are preceded by a plus sign, and deletion lines are preceded by a minus sign.
>
> A hunk begins with **range information** and is immediately followed with the line additions, line deletions, and any number of the contextual lines. The range information is surrounded by double-at signs, and combines onto a single line what appears on two lines in the context format (above). The format of the range information line is as follows:
>
> ```
>     @@ -l,s +l,s @@ optional section heading
> ```
>
> ...

The idea of any format that `diff` throws at you is to transform a *source* file into a *destination* file following a series of steps. Let's see a simple example of how this works with *unified format*.

Given the following files:

#### from.txt

```
a
b
```

#### to.txt

```
a
c
```

The output of `diff -u from.txt to.txt` is:

```
--- frokm.txt   2015-03-17 04:34:47.076997087 -0430
+++ to.txt      2015-03-17 04:35:27.872996388 -0430
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 a
-b
+c
```

Explanation. Header description:

```
--- from.txt    2015-03-17 22:42:18.575039925 -0430  <-- from-file time stamp
+++ to.txt      2015-03-17 22:42:10.495040064 -0430  <-- to-file time stamp
```

This diff contains just one hunk (only one set of changes to turn file *form.txt* into *to.txt*):

```
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@  <-- A hunk, a block describing chages between both files, there could be several of these in the diff -u output
   ^    ^
   |   (+) means that this change starts at line 1 and involves 2 lines in the to.txt file
  (-) means that this change starts at line 1 and involves 2 lines of the from.txt file
```

Next, the list of changes:

```
 a   <-- This line remains the same in both files, so it won't be changed
-b   <-- This line has to be removed from the "from.txt" file to transform it into the "to.txt" file
+c   <-- This line has to be added to the "from.txt" file to transform it into the "to.txt" file
```

Here are some StackOverflow answers with really nice info about this subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950496/1041822
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530012/1041822

And some other useful documentation:

https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/
http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=164293

Answer (score 3):

The term *unified* was made up.  Better, perhaps would have been to call it "concise".

The point of `diff -u` is that it is a more concise representation than context diff.  Quoting from the original description of Wayne Davison's posting of `unidiff` to *comp.sources.misc* (volume 14, 31 Aug 90):

```
I've created a new context diff format that combines the old and new chunks into 
one unified hunk.  The result?  The unified context diff, or "unidiff."         
                                                                            
Posting your patch using a unidiff will usually cut its size down by around     
25% (I've seen from 12% to 48%, depending on how many redundant context lines   
are removed).  Even if the diffs are generated with only 2 lines of context,    
the savings still average around 20%.                                           
                                                                            
Keep in mind that *no information is lost* by the conversion process.  Only
the redundancy of having multiple identical context lines.  [...]
```

Here are some useful links:

- [How to read a patch or diff and understand its structure to apply it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206044536/http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/)
- [What is the format of a patch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987372/what-is-the-format-of-a-patch-file)

Not useful (and misleading)

- [2.2.2 Unified Format](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html), which appears to omit attribution.