# Can't install zbarlight on windows 10

Tags: python

I am trying to follow the steps at this article
https://ruvi-d.medium.com/getting-zbarlight-to-work-on-windows-a3dc643dba18

At step 3 I got this desription

```
Apply this patch https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff to the cygwinccompiler.py file in the same folder
```

How to apply this patch? I have no idea how to perform such a step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the steps indicated I think you should open your terminal and follow theses steps :

- First go in the folder indicated : `cd <your_python_path>\Lib\distutils`.
- Second -  according to the author of the article, a file named `cygwinccompiler.py` is supposed to be present, the patch is supposed to be applied on it.
- Third download (or copy as you prefered) the patch file in the current directory, lets name the patch file `patch.diff` (for reminder here is its link https://bugs.python.org/file40608/patch.diff).
- Then you must run :

```py
pip install patch
python -m patch patch.diff
```

Since the name of the file to patch is present in `patch.diff` you do not have to precise the destination file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed the steps you mentioned and encountered an error `C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'patch.diff' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'patch' while trying to find 'patch.diff')`

Comment: I've made a mistake, you should execute `python -m patch` instead of `python -m patch.diff`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this line `python -m patch patch.diff` and worked as expected. I could copy and paste the lines with the blue plus but I prefered to do it through python to learn something new.

Comment: What does this line mean exactly `@@ -82,7 +82,18 @@ def get_msvcr():`. I could get 82 is the first line of the new patched data and the def get_Msvcr() is the function name .. what about 7 and 18?

Comment: You will find a good answer to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113646/12113368