# Adminer login via a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, adminer

I am running Nginx which is configured to allow me to access several resources on another server which is available as a reverse proxy.  For example

```
main server:http://example.com
slave: http://example.com/slave
adminer on slave: http://example.com/slave/admin/adminer.php
```

Everything is all right so far.  I enter my DB user name and password in Adminer and the trouble begins.  Examining the headers returned by Adminer post-login I have noticed that it sends back this header:

```
Location: /admin/adminer.php?username=user
```

This is the root of the trouble.  On my browser this, naturally, gets interpreted as meaning relative to the current server rather than the reverse proxy.   I tried hacking the adminer code after locating the one place where it has a Location header but that just stopped it dead in its tracks.

How can I prevent this from happening?  I have considered running a Lua script on Nginx that examines the header and replaces it but it strikes me that even if I get that to work I will be getting my server to do a great deal of unnecessary work.

### Edit

After exploring the issue a bit more I am starting to think that adminer may not being doing much wrong.  It actually uses the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value to construct the location header and that happens to have little part from `/admin/adminer.php`.  I have noted that the referer, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] has the full original request path `http://example.com/slave/admin/adminer.php`.  So the solution would be to send back the location `/slave/admin/adminer.php?username=user`.

Easy?  Well, the issue is that in my setup `/slave/` is going to be variable so I need to resolve it in code.  I can probably do that reasonably easily with a spot of PHP but I wonder... surely there is an easier alternative provided by Nginx?

I should perhaps mention:

- Ubuntu 14.04 on both master & slave
- Nginx 1.6.2 installed vial apt-get nginx-extras (the Lua module enabled flavor)
- php5-fpm 5.5.9
- MariaDB 10
- Adminer 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit the same problem and the most simple fix I could come up with is to patch the adminer PHP script. I simply hardcoded `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` at the start of `adminer.php` like this:

```
--- adminer.php 2015-10-22 12:31:18.549068888 +0300
+++ adminer.php 2015-10-22 12:31:40.097069554 +0300
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 <?php
+$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "/slave/admin/adminer.php";
 /** Adminer - Compact database management
 * @link http://www.adminer.org/
 * @author Jakub Vrana, http://www.vrana.cz/
```

If you put the above in a file called `fix` you can simply run
`patch < /path/to/fix` in the directory containing `adminer.php` you should get the correctly working version. Running `patch -R < /path/to/fix` will restore the original behavior if needed.

---

To understand the structure of a patch file read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987372/what-is-the-format-of-a-patch-file).

Comment: thank you very much for this tip.  It is going to be a life saver.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and this is how I resolved it:

```
upstream adminer {
    server adminer;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /adminer/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/adminer";
        proxy_pass http://adminer/;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Original Question asks about nginx reverse proxy.