# Hunk does not apply right after split

Tags: git

I am trying to edit a certain hunk with a git: I use `git add -p`, then press `s` and then `e`. I make no changes (initially I tried to), save the file and it says that hunk does not apply.

Easy example:

1. Create a file with the following content:

   ```
   aaa
   bbb
   ccc
   ```
2. Commit it
3. Add changes (three lines on the top and one line before the last line), so the file looks like

   ```
   111
   222
   333
   aaa
   bbb
   444
   ccc
   ```
4. Run `git add -p`
5. Press `s` to split
6. Press `e` to edit. Edit nothing (really nothing)
7. Save file with no changes
8. It does not apply.
9. ???

Any ideas..?

Comment: I bet it's to do with the line numbers at the top of the patch.

Comment: Like this `@@ -4,9 +4,12 @@`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987372/what-is-the-format-of-a-patch-file

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unfortunately, no. I know what they mean and usually is able to fix them so the hunk applies. I tried anything I can think of in this case and it didn't work out. However, those numbers are `@@ -1 +1,5 @@` which looks kind of strange. And it definetely is something about moving the very first line down. If I leave it, this works just fine.

Comment: Step 6 says "edit". What did you do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox NOTHING =) You can do nothing and it won't apply. You can easily reproduce it. Some friendв of mine and colleagues confirmed several issue on this example

Comment: The standard advice is: don't do that.  If you want to split the hunk, don't edit it.  Instead, edit the hunk and perform the split while editing.  It's slightly more painful, but gets around the problem.

Comment: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-add-patch-bug-with-split-edit-td2171634.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply/

Comment: It's a bug in Git. See William Pursell's first link (to nabble.com) above.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you. For sure, there are better ways to do it, but, however, I faced this issue and became interested in the reasons. It is a bug but there was no any attention paid to it (according to the link you sent). Also, I read the question you send and tried to play along with the numbers like you offered in your answer there, but I didn't manage to find the right ones yet.